# Salesforce LWC Worklog Timesheet add weekly hours problem

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, controller

[image]the purpose of the worklog creation code is to assign a project-based weekly assignment to the user and enter the daily working hours.

Users need to be able to edit it and assign project-based timesheets, so the saved timeline should not be reset until edited. The problem is that no matter how hard I try, "please add weekly hours" error pops up. I can't find the error in the code. I tried at least 20 hours but couldn't solve it. This really upset me. I would be very happy if you could help.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getProjects from '@salesforce/apex/timeSheetEntryController.getProjects';
import insertTimesheets from '@salesforce/apex/timeSheetEntryController.insertTimesheets';
import getProject from '@salesforce/apex/timeSheetEntryController.getProject';
import getTimesheetItems from '@salesforce/apex/timeSheetEntryController.getTimesheetItems';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import UserNameFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import UserIDFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Id';

const DAYSARRAY = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const DAYSARRAYFULL = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

export default class TimesheetEntryLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track currentUserName;
    @track currentUserID;
    @track selectedProjectID;
    @track currentDate;
    @track dates = [];
    @track projectOptions = [];
    @track projectvsTimesheetLines = [];
    @track timesheetLines = [];
    @track daysVsTotalObj = {};
    @track dayVsDateObj = {};
    @track finalTimesheetVar = [];
    @track timesheetId;
    @track showSpinner;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: Id, fields: [UserNameFIELD, UserIDFIELD] })
    currentUserInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.currentUserName = data.fields.Name.value || '';
            this.currentUserID = data.fields.Id.value || '';
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.currentUserName = '';
            this.currentUserID = '';
        }
    }

    @wire(getProjects)
    fetchProjects({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.projectOptions = data;
            this.setDefaultLine();
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching projects', error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getProject, { ProjName: '$defaultProject' })
    fetchProject({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.selectedProjectID = data || '';
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching project', error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getTimesheetItems)
    fetchTimesheetItems({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.timesheetLines = data;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching timesheet items', error);
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.dates = this.setDates(new Date());
        this.currentDate = new Date();
        this.setDaysTotal();
    }

    setDaysTotal() {
        DAYSARRAYFULL.forEach(day => {
            this.daysVsTotalObj[day] = 0;
        });
    }

    handleLineDelete(event) {
        const searchIndex = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.projectvsTimesheetLines = this.projectvsTimesheetLines.filter(item => item.index !== searchIndex);
        this.timesheetLines = this.timesheetLines.filter(item => !item.includes(searchIndex));
        this.updateDailyHours();
    }

    handleCancel() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    handleProjectChange(event) {
        this.projectvsTimesheetLines[0].project = event.target.value;
        this.selectedProjectID = event.target.value + "-99";
    }

    handleDateChange(event) {
        this.dates = this.setDates(new Date(event.target.value));
        this.projectvsTimesheetLines = [];
        this.timesheetLines = [];
        this.setDefaultLine();
        this.setDaysTotal();
    }

    handleInsert() {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        if (this.validateTimeSheets()) {
            this.showSpinner = false;
            return;
        }
        if (this.finalTimesheetVar.length === 0 || !this.dayVsDateObj['Monday']) {
            this.showToast('Error', 'Invalid arguments. Please add weekly hours.');
            this.showSpinner = false;
            return;
        }
        insertTimesheets({
            listOfLines: this.finalTimesheetVar,
            startDate: this.dayVsDateObj['Monday'],
            submitForApproval: false // Değiştirildi
        })
        
            .then(result => {
                this.timesheetId = result;
                this.showToast('Success', 'Timesheet created!');
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.timesheetId,
                        objectApiName: 'Timesheet__c',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });
                this.showSpinner = false;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showToast('Error', error.body.message);
                this.showSpinner = false;
            });
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        if (this.validateTimeSheets()) {
            this.showSpinner = false;
            return;
        }
        if (this.finalTimesheetVar.length === 0 || !this.dayVsDateObj['Monday']) {
            this.showToast('Error', 'Invalid arguments. Please add weekly hours.');
            this.showSpinner = false;
            return;
        }
        insertTimesheets({
            listOfLines: this.finalTimesheetVar,
            startDate: this.dayVsDateObj['Monday'],
            submitForApproval: true // Değiştirilmedi
        })
            .then(result => {
                this.timesheetId = result;
                this.showToast('Success', 'Timesheet created!');
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.timesheetId,
                        objectApiName: 'Timesheet__c',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });
                this.showSpinner = false;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showToast('Error', error.body.message);
                this.showSpinner = false;
            });
    }
    
    validateTimeSheets() {
        if (this.timesheetLines.length === 0) {
            this.showToast('Error', 'Please add weekly hours.');
            return true;
        }
        const indexProject = {};
        const projectList = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox');
        projectList.forEach(item => {
            indexProject[item.dataset.index] = item.value;
        });
        this.finalTimesheetVar = [];
        this.timesheetLines.forEach(item => {
            const parts = item.split('-');
            const day = parts[1];
            if (day in this.dayVsDateObj) {
                const updatedItem = item.replace(parts[0], indexProject[parts[0]]);
                this.finalTimesheetVar.push(updatedItem);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    setDefaultLine() {
        const index = 0;
        const defaultLine = {
            index,
            project: this.selectedProjectID,
            days: []
        };
        this.projectvsTimesheetLines.push(defaultLine);
        DAYSARRAY.forEach(day => {
            defaultLine.days.push(day);
        });
        this.timesheetLines.push(`${index}-${DAYSARRAY[0]}`);
        this.updateDailyHours();
    }

    setDates(startDate) {
        const dates = [];
        const currentDate = new Date(startDate);
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            dates.push(this.formatDate(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }

    formatDate(date) {
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let day = date.getDate();
        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    }

    updateDailyHours() {
        const newDaysTotal = {};
        DAYSARRAYFULL.forEach(day => {
            newDaysTotal[day] = 0;
        });
        const updatedTimesheetLines = [];
        this.timesheetLines.forEach(item => {
            const parts = item.split('-');
            const projectIndex = parseInt(parts[0]);
            const day = parts[1];
            const inputElement = this.template.querySelector(`[data-index="${projectIndex}"][data-day="${day}"]`);
            if (inputElement) {
                const hours = inputElement.value;
                updatedTimesheetLines.push(`${projectIndex}-${day}-${hours}`);
                newDaysTotal[day] += parseInt(hours) || 0;
            }
        });
        this.timesheetLines = updatedTimesheetLines;
        this.daysVsTotalObj = newDaysTotal;
    }
    

    handleHourChange(event) {
        const projectIndex = event.target.dataset.index;
        const day = event.target.dataset.day;
        const hours = event.target.value;
        const searchIndex = this.timesheetLines.indexOf(`${projectIndex}-${day}`);
        if (searchIndex === -1) {
            this.timesheetLines.push(`${projectIndex}-${day}`);
        }
        const updatedTimesheetLines = [];
        this.timesheetLines.forEach(item => {
            if (item.includes(`${projectIndex}-${day}`)) {
                updatedTimesheetLines.push(`${projectIndex}-${day}-${hours}`);
            } else {
                updatedTimesheetLines.push(item);
            }
        });
        this.timesheetLines = updatedTimesheetLines;
        this.updateDailyHours();
    }

    addNewLine() {
        const index = this.projectvsTimesheetLines.length;
        const newLine = {
            index,
            project: this.selectedProjectID,
            days: []
        };
        this.projectvsTimesheetLines.push(newLine);
        DAYSARRAY.forEach(day => {
            newLine.days.push(day);
        });
        this.timesheetLines.push(`${index}-${DAYSARRAY[0]}`);
        this.updateDailyHours();
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant = 'info') {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

```java
public with sharing class timeSheetEntryController {
    public class Option {
        @AuraEnabled 
        public String label{ get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled 
        public String value{ get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled 
        public String ID{ get; set; }
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Timesheet__c getTimesheetForWeek(String weekStartDateStr, Id userId) {
        Date weekStartDate;
        try {
            weekStartDate = Date.valueOf(weekStartDateStr);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid date format. Please enter date as YYYY-MM-DD.');
        }
        
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Employee_Rate_Id__c, End_Date__c, Start_Date__c, Status__c
                FROM Timesheet__c
                WHERE Start_Date__c = :weekStartDate AND User__c = :userId];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c> getTimesheetLineItems(Id timesheetId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Entry_Date__c, Hours__c, Project__c 
                FROM Timesheet_Line_Items__c 
                WHERE Timesheet__c = :timesheetId];
    }

    public static void saveTimesheet(Timesheet__c timesheet, List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c> lineItems) {
        if (timesheet == null || lineItems == null || lineItems.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Please add weekly hours.');
        }
        upsert timesheet;
        if (timesheet.Id == null) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Upsert operation failed on Timesheet');
        }
        for(Timesheet_Line_Items__c item : lineItems) {
            item.Timesheet__c = timesheet.Id;
        }
        upsert lineItems;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Option> getProjects() {
        try {
            List<Option> projectOptions = new List<Option>();
            for(Project__c pro: [SELECT Id, Name, Project_ID__c FROM Project__c ORDER BY Name ASC]) {
                Option newOp = new Option();
                newOp.label = pro.Name;
                newOp.value = pro.Id;
                projectOptions.add(newOp);
            }
            return projectOptions;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getProject(String ProjName) {
        try {
            Project__c proj = [SELECT Id FROM Project__c WHERE Name = :ProjName LIMIT 1];
            return proj.Id;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String updateTimesheet(Timesheet__c timesheet) {
        try {
            if (timesheet == null || timesheet.Id == null) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid Timesheet');
            }
            upsert timesheet;
            return 'Timesheet updated successfully!';
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String insertTimesheets(List<String> listOfLines, String startDate, Boolean submitForApproval) {
    if (listOfLines == null || listOfLines.isEmpty() || startDate == null || startDate.trim() == '') {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Arguments cannot be null or empty');
    }
    
    Map<String, Integer> keyVsHours = new Map<String, Integer>();
    List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c> lineList = new List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c>();
    
    Date startDate1 = Date.valueOf(startDate);
    Date endDate = startDate1.addDays(6);
    
    Timesheet__c sheet = new Timesheet__c();
    sheet.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    sheet.Start_Date__c = startDate1;
    sheet.Status__c = submitForApproval ? 'SUBMITTED' : 'Draft';
    sheet.End_Date__c = endDate;
    
    try {
        insert sheet;

        for (String each : listOfLines) {
            List<String> temp = each.split('-');
            if (temp.size() != 3) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid line format');
            }
            String projectKey = temp[0];
            String entryDateStr = temp[1];
            Integer hours = Integer.valueOf(temp[2]);

            String key = projectKey + '-' + entryDateStr;
            if (keyVsHours.containsKey(key)) {
                hours += keyVsHours.get(key);
            }
            keyVsHours.put(key, hours);
        }

        for (String key : keyVsHours.keySet()) {
            List<String> temp = key.split('-');
            String projectKey = temp[0];
            String entryDateStr = temp[1];
            Date entryDate = Date.valueOf(entryDateStr);
            Integer hours = keyVsHours.get(key);

            Timesheet_Line_Items__c line = new Timesheet_Line_Items__c();
            line.Entry_Date__c = entryDate;
            line.Timesheet__c = sheet.Id;
            line.Hours__c = hours;
            lineList.add(line);
        }

        insert lineList;

        // Kaydetme işlemi başarılı olduğunda bu satıra gelinir
        saveTimesheet(sheet, lineList);

        if (submitForApproval) {
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req1.setObjectId(sheet.Id);
            req1.setSubmitterId(UserInfo.getUserId());                 
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
        }

        if (submitForApproval) {
            return 'Timesheet submitted successfully!';
        } else {
            return 'Timesheet saved successfully!';
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

    
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c> getTimesheetItems() {
        try {
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Hours__c, Entry_Date__c, Timesheet__c FROM Timesheet_Line_Items__c];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Timesheet__c> getTimesheets() {
        try {
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Status__c, User__c FROM Timesheet__c];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Timesheet__c getRecord(String recordId) {
        try {
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Status__c, User__c FROM Timesheet__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used 'breakpoint' from the console? 
Also, if I were you, I would fetch all org's metadata using VSCode (or similar IDE) and search for "please add weekly hours" as I can see it is a custom error message.

Comment: Try checking this Apex method:  `public static List<Timesheet_Line_Items__c> getTimesheetItems()`. It could be returning null records. As per your LWC, `validateTimeSheets()`, the execution might be returning back and throwing the error: "Please add weekly hours". 
Better to use 'breakpoints' from your browser to pinpoint the flow and see which `wire` is getting no records. Refer: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/

Comment: validateTimeSheets() {
        if (!this.timesheetLines || this.timesheetLines.length === 0) {
            console.log('timesheetLines:', this.timesheetLines); // Hata ayıklama için console.log ekleyin
            this.showToast('Error', 'Please add weekly hours.');
            return true;
        }    yes that method fire that its good idea to try ı will sir thank you a lot